# How to figure out if the app is using local storage 1 or 0 on iOS7?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'm trying to use Coredata with iCloud on iOS7.
When configuring CoredataUbiquitous store, we get console log messages like:

`CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~123456789:CoreDataUbiquitous
Using local storage: 1`

Then, the following log few seconds later.

`CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~123456789:CoreDataUbiquitous
Using local storage: 0`

So, I understand the first log is saying that we're using a fallback store, and the later confirms that we have an access to the iCloud.

But how do I know this inside the code? How can I detect whether the app is still using a fallback store or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there does not seem to be any such notification, I have been looking for it too. There is obviously NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification which will occur when connected to iCloud AND there have been some data changes - but sensing connection to iCloud when no data has changed does not seem to be possible.

Ali